# How to use Pl/SQL Collection within a Function

Tags: oracle, function, collections, plsql

For an assignment the recommendation was to use collections. Simply said I need to chop a string in several substrings, reverse the order of those strings and put them all together.

Omitted actual code in because it crashes at the declare part.
 Keep getting the error: **stringlist1 is not a procedure or is undefined**
So for some reason the type I try to assign to stringlist1 isn't doing it.
Do you guys know why this is happening? And if this isn't fixable what is a neat workaround other than making a variable for every row in the collection?

Things I tried:

  * Create my own type in a "create type" statement beforehand
  * Creating the type in an anonymous block before the function
  * Creating a varchar collection within the declare part of the function
  * The dbms package used below
  * Renaming the hell out of it
  * Trying to initiate the type like stringlist1 dbms_utility.name_array := dbms_utility.name_array();

```
Create or replace FUNCTION TEST (p_number varchar2)
RETURN varchar2
IS
stringlist1 dbms_utility.name_array;
stringlist2 dbms_utility.name_array;
BEGIN
stringlist1('test');
stringlist2('test');
dbms.output.put_line(stringlist1(1));
return stringlist1(1);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

String can be added to array like `stringlist1(1) := 'test';`

So your code will be compile when corrected like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST (p_number VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   stringlist1   DBMS_UTILITY.name_array;
   stringlist2   DBMS_UTILITY.name_array;
BEGIN
   stringlist1(1) := 'test';
   stringlist2(1) :=  'test';
   dbms_output.put_line (stringlist1 (1));
   RETURN stringlist1 (1);
END;
```

PS: Package name is not `dmbs.output`, correct one is `dbms_output`.

Comment: I already expected it was some dumb oversight of mine, thanks a lot, that worked !